# T4 Template failing with MissingMethodException on imported assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, templates, t4

I have created a T4 template and decided to create some helper classes to cleanup the template code.  I created a new class project in my solution for my helper classes, referenced the assembly in my template and imported the namespace.

Here is an example:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\MySolution.SqlMetaHelper\bin\Debug\MySolution.SqlMetaHelper    .dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo" #>
<#@ import namespace="MySolution.SqlMetaHelper" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#
string @namespace = "MySolution.Data";
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection("localhost", "sa", "password");  
Server server = new Server(connection);
Database database = server.Databases["MySolution"];
#>
namespace <#= @namespace #>
{
<#
foreach (Table table in database.Tables)
{
#>
    public interface I<#= table.Name #>
    {
        //Properties
<#
    foreach (ColumnMeta column in table.Columns.Cast<Column>().Select(c => new ColumnMeta(c)))
    {
#>
        //<#=column.Name#>
<#
    }
#>
    }
<#
}
#>
}
```

The template fails to execute and returns this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Running transformation: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void MySolution.SqlMetaHelper.ColumnMeta..ctor(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column)'.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingE69FE551E9A42AE5D542A4EC2CDCECEDBDBC96F903EFDB8864E380652948850C270A5AC8C04E0B0F9368C0530BF3447DEAFC3716CC5CE03ABD37589675749A74.GeneratedTextTransformation.<>c.<TransformText>b__0_0(Column c)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingE69FE551E9A42AE5D542A4EC2CDCECEDBDBC96F903EFDB8864E380652948850C270A5AC8C04E0B0F9368C0530BF3447DEAFC3716CC5CE03ABD37589675749A74.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() MySolution.Data C:\Users\me\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MySolution\MySolution.Data\Entities.tt    1
```

I have tried many things with no success and I cannot find anything that matches my scenario on the web.  I have a feeling it has something to do with the references to the "Microsoft.SqlServer.???" assemblies since they are referenced by both the template and the external library and perhaps are different versions but I'm not sure how I would fix this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by referencing the same assemblies in the helper class projects.

I made sure the Microsoft.SqlServer.??? references were set to copy local and then i updated the assembly section of the t4 template to use the assemblies copied to the build foler like this:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\MySolution.SqlMetaHelper\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\MySolution.SqlMetaHelper\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\MySolution.SqlMetaHelper\bin\Debug\MySolution.SqlMetaHelper.dll" #>
```

The GAC assembly versions must have not matched what assemblies referenced by the project.